# Uploading & downloading a file via REST

Tags: rest, file-upload, download

I have to expose a REST API for allowing file upload and download. The files are not accessible via URI and they are present outside of the Web root. How do I stream the file for upload and download in java?

Comment: very general question, are you looking to do that in any specific technology stack? .net? php? java?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole service:

```
> POST /files HTTP/1.1
> Content-Type: ...
> Content-Length: ...
> 
> [ENTITY BODY HERE]

< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Location: http://service.org/files/1

> GET /files/1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: service.org
```

It is not necessary to directly expose files from the server, it is enough to implement service bound to particular URI pattern(in this example /files/{FILE_ID}) and maintain this mapping properly. From the URI handler method you just need to a) properly select file; b) send file contents to output stream;